# Retag ambiguous [failsafe] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

I fell at *[How last thrown Exception contains previously thrown Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9500874/1064325)* question today, and it was tagged with [failsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failsafe). After reading its tag wiki describing it with `The Maven Failsafe Plugin is used to run integration tests with Maven build tools.` (which is the same description of [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-failsafe-plugin)), I decided to retag it to [fault-tolerance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fault-tolerance), but I feel it might not be the best way to resolve that.

Obviously, there's a problem here.

- There are 52 questions tagged with [failsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failsafe)

  - ~18 of them isn't about the [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-failsafe-plugin) ¹
  - 7 of them was also tagged with [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-failsafe-plugin)
- Both [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-failsafe-plugin) and [failsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failsafe) have only 2 followers

As a suggestion to resolve past and further potential ambiguity problems, there are a few approaches (the striked ones were eliminated since some commenters have discouraged them):

1. <del>Change [failsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failsafe) tag wiki to *failsafe* in the broader meaning, and everything *might* be alright.</del>
2. <del>Make [failsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failsafe) tag a synonym of [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-failsafe-plugin) + Retag the non-Maven-related [failsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failsafe) questions.</del>
3. <del>Retag the non-Maven-related [failsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failsafe) questions to [something-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/something-else)* + Burninate [failsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failsafe).</del>
4. Retag the Maven-related [failsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failsafe) questions to [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-failsafe-plugin) + Retag the non-Maven-related [failsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failsafe) questions to [something-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/something-else).

#### Questions:

- Do you agree with the ambiguity?
- If so, do you agree with the remaining suggestion?
- Which [something-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/something-else) tag should we use for the non-Maven-related questions?

  - [fault-tolerance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fault-tolerance) (just as I've done)
  - a new [failsafe-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failsafe-design)
  - or other (which?)

---

¹ Here is the list with the 18 non-Maven-related questions tagged with [failsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failsafe) (needs revision):

1. [fail-safe .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653696/1064325)
2. [Fail safe code for cgi python scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4062750/1064325)
3. [Failsafe Coding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5788369/1064325)
4. [how to protect my process from being killed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6538587/1064325)
5. [Handling exceptions that are caused by logging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6942587/1064325)
6. [Can a git repository be corrupted if a command modifying it crashes or is aborted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8384101/1064325)
7. [Failover strategy for database application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10064718/1064325)
8. [javascript fail-safe plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10553785/1064325)
9. [reactor vs proactor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11859332/1064325)
10. [Arduino Fail-Safe Mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12894029/1064325)
11. https://stackoverflow.com/q/12672217/1064325
12. https://stackoverflow.com/q/13432909/1064325
13. [Achieving Fail-safe behaviour in flow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14653881/1064325)
14. [fail fast iterator implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19257755/1064325)
15. [PHP Failsafe If Unable to get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24659347/1064325)
16. [Concurrent Hashmap - Fail safe issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25688963/1064325)
17. [How EnumMap fail safe though it is not syncronized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28735047/1064325)
18. [How last thrown Exception contains previously thrown Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9500874/1064325)

Comment: @KevinBrown I'll add your suggestion to the list.

Comment: I think retagging to remove [failsafe] is the best option.  Since failsafe has at least two meanings in this community, it is not a synonym of anything (in this system, a synonym can only point to one thing).