# Tag used incorrectly / ambiguous meaning (tag fluid)

Tags: support, tags

Currently, the tag **fluid** is used incorrectly in a number of questions.

There are 2 different meanings for **fluid** in question:

- tag [fluid-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluid-layout): *"A Fluid Layout, sometimes also referred to as a liquid layout, is a CSS technique in which the majority of the page components have percentage widths, and thus adjust to the user's screen resolution."*
- tag [fluid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluid) *"Fluid is a an XML-based templating system for TYPO3. With Fluid, all the code for the view logic moves to the template - e.g. loops, if/else switches and similar."*. This is specific to [[typo3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typo3) or [[neoscms]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neoscms).

Currently, there are 374 questions tagged with **fluid** and not **typo3** / **neoscms** (request: [[fluid] -[neoscms] -[typo3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluid+-neoscms+-typo3)), which are *most probably* (I did not check them all, just glanced through) tagged incorrectly (using tag **fluid** instead of tag **fluid-layout**). There is a total of about 1000 tagged with [fluid], so about a third is most probably tagged incorectly.

What's the best procedure for normal user if they see questions tagged incorrectly (e.g. editing the questions and changing the tags or leaving a comment?

What is the best way to address this in general (apart from manually editing every single one)? E.g. should the tag in question be renamed?

I found a similar question to this question, however with no answer: [Retag ambiguous [failsafe] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286980/retag-ambiguous-failsafe-tag)

Personally, I think the drop down tag-hint when typing the tags is extremely helpful and should be sufficient, but apparently not.

[image: Drop down tag hints]

Comment: Ick, tag fluid leaking out all over the place...

Comment: suggested title: Tag meaning is too [fluid]